# GStreamer cannot pickle 'Sample' object

Tags: python, apache-kafka, gstreamer, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to send an encoded frame sample using Kafka, but Kafka requires that the sample to be Serializable, so the following error emerge:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'Sample' object
```

is there a way to pickle Gstreamer objects?

My pipeline:

```
"rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.6.28/sub latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=640,height=640  ! appsink name=sink sync=false"
```

code that generates the error:

```
sample = self.appsink.try_pull_sample(Gst.SECOND)
 producer.produce("testTopic", pickle.dumps(sample), "1", callback=delivery_callback)
```

I have used JSON.dumps, bytes, ArrayBytes with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not require a Serializable class. You can manually define a value serializer in the Producer constructor, then you need to have it return a function that accepts an object and returns bytes types.

Pickle is not a recommended Kafka data format since it's mostly Python specific, and other consumers in other languages may want to consume that topic. Therefore, binary formats like Protobuf or Avro would be cross language

Also worth pointing out that Kafka has a default message size of 1MB, so video streaming is not a common use case with it

Comment: The idea is that I can't serialize the objects, so if I implemented my own serializer, I can't transform the object to bytes. 

All our Kafka clients are written in python, but I'll check solutions provided.

I increased message size to around 30MB, what do you recommend for video streaming 
or to be more precise I want to send a (frame with meta data) to a client without losing data.

Comment: The whole purpose of defining your own serializer is to make bytes from any object. And you should use actual video streaming technology like HLS. Kafka is for log events, not sequenced binary blobs like video or audio segments